# Why do I keep getting an Attribute error (circular import)

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

So I'm trying to learn how to code and when I try to split up my code into multiple files using the *import* function, I keep getting an Attribute error. It says that it is most likely due to a circular import yet I can't figure out what to do.

main.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import distances as dc

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")
root.title("UnitConverter - Main Menu")

global headLabel
headLabel = Label(master=root, text="UnitConverter", font=("Aptos Semibold", 20))
headLabel.pack()

global subLabel
subLabel = Label(master=root,text="Select what you would like to convert:",
                 font=("Aptos SemiBold", 15))
subLabel.pack()

buttons=[
    {"text": "Distances", "x": 50, "y": 100, "command": dc.distance_cmd},
    {"text": "Weights", "x": 209, "y": 100},
    {"text": "Fluids", "x": 360, "y": 100},
    {"text": "Currencies", "x": 50, "y": 200},
    {"text": "Time", "x": 209, "y": 200}
]

buttonStyle = ttk.Style()
buttonStyle.configure("my.TButton", font=("Aptos SemiBold", 13))

for button_info in buttons:
    button = ttk.Button(root, text=button_info["text"], style="my.TButton",
                        command=button_info["command"])
    button.place(x=button_info["x"], y=button_info["y"])

root.mainloop()

def hideButtons():
    for button_info in buttons:
        button.place_forget()
```

distances.py:

```
import main_copy as mc

def distance_cmd():
    mc.root.title("UnitConverter - Distances")
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\simon\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\Distance Converter\main_copy.py", line 3, in <module>
    import distances as dc
  File "c:\Users\simon\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\Distance Converter\distances.py", line 1, in <module>
    import main_copy as mc
  File "c:\Users\simon\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\Distance Converter\main_copy.py", line 19, in <module>
    {"text": "Distances", "x": 50, "y": 100, "command": dc.distance_cmd},
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'distances' has no attribute 'distance_cmd' (most likely due to a circular import)
PS C:\Users\simon\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\Distance Converter>
```

I honestly don't know what to try anymore but the goal would be to be able to write fucntions in the *distance.py* file and be able to use them in the *main.py* file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.  Then write the functions in distance.py and the use them in main.py.   Don't import stuff from main_copy in distance.py and then import stuff from distance into main_copy.  If you find yourself doing this circular import, you'll need to rethink how you write your modules.

Comment: As said in the comment, avoid importing *main* module inside other modules.  For your case, suggest to pass `root` to `distance_cmd()` as an argument instead.

Comment: Could you add the code from main_copy.py as that seems to be where the error lies

Answer (score 1):

To explicitly show what is mentioned in the comments, in `distances.py` remove the:

```
import main_copy as mc
```

line and add `root` as an argument to the `distance_cmd` function:

```
def distance_cmd(root):
    root.title("UnitConverter - Distances")
```

Then, in `main_copy.py`, when you need to use `distance_cmd`, you can either create a [`lambda`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) function, where `distance_cmd` will be called with `root` supplied, e.g.,

```
buttons=[
    {
        "text": "Distances",
        "x": 50,
        "y": 100,
        "command": lambda : dc.distance_cmd(root)
    },
    {"text": "Weights", "x": 209, "y": 100},
    {"text": "Fluids", "x": 360, "y": 100},
    {"text": "Currencies", "x": 50, "y": 200},
    {"text": "Time", "x": 209, "y": 200}
]
```

or, equivalently create a [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function that explicitly passes `root` to the `distance_cmd` function, e.g.,

```
from functools import partial

...

def 

buttons=[
    {
        "text": "Distances",
        "x": 50,
        "y": 100,
        "command": partial(dc.distance_cmd, root)
    },
    {"text": "Weights", "x": 209, "y": 100},
    {"text": "Fluids", "x": 360, "y": 100},
    {"text": "Currencies", "x": 50, "y": 200},
    {"text": "Time", "x": 209, "y": 200}
]
```

I'd have a preference for a `partial` over a `lambda`.

Comment: Note that `dc.distance_cmd(root)` will execute immediately, use lambda instead.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited it to use a `lambda` or a `partial` - I lean towards preferring `partial`s

Comment: Your *lambda* definition should not have argument because the callback for `command` option of a button expects no argument.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks, I didn't actually know you could have lambdas without arguments, so I've learned something new! I've edited the answer now.